# How to prove $\mu(K)\le\int_\limits Xfd\mu<\mu(K)+\epsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, measure-theory

> Let $(X,\tau,\mathcal A,\mu)$ a space that satisfy hypothesis $(H)$. Prove that for all compact $K\subseteq X$ and $\epsilon>0$, exist $f\in C_c(X)$ such that $f(x)=1,\forall x\in K$ and $\mu(K)\le\int_\limits Xfd\mu<\mu(K)+\epsilon$.

Seems natural to try to apply Urysohn's lemma. There is only one hypothesis that I don't see and that is required in Urysohn's lemma: for all $V\in\tau,K\subseteq V$. With this hypothesis I can conclude

that $f\in C_c(X)$, $0\le f\le 1,$ $f=1,\forall x\in K$ and support of $f\in V$.

By other hand, $K\in\mathcal A$ and $\mu(K)<\infty$ thus by 7) $\mu(K)=\sup\{\mu(F)\mid  F \text{ is closed}, F\subseteq K\}$

Am I on the right track to arrive to $\mu(K)\le\int_\limits Xfd\mu<\mu(K)+\epsilon$ ? I do not know how to proceed

Please help

---

Hypothesis $(H)$

1.$(X,\mathcal A,\mu)$ is a measurable space

2$.(X,\tau)$ is a topological locally compact Hausdorff space

3.$\mu$ is complete

4.if $K\subseteq X $ is compact then $\mu(K)<\infty$

5.$\mathcal B(X)\subseteq \mathcal A$

6.if $E\in\mathcal A$ then $\mu(E)=\inf\{\mu(U)\mid U \text{ is open},E\subseteq U\}$

7.if $E\in\mathcal A$ with $\mu(E)<\infty$ or $E\in\tau$ then $\mu(E)=\sup\{\mu(F)\mid  F \text{ is closed},F\subseteq E\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea: having $\varepsilon>0$, let $U$ be an open set with $K \subseteq U$ such that $\mu(U) - \mu(K) < \varepsilon$. This can be done by $4$ and $6$: the measure is finite (and defined, by $5$) on compacta and outer regular. With some effort make sure that $\overline{U}$ is compact too (local compactness) and so the $f$ below will have compact support. Then by $2$ the space $X$ is Tychonoff (completely regular) so by a standard fact we can replace the point by a compact set (so this is not Urysohn's lemma; we don't have normality necessarily!), and get a continuous $f:X \to [0,1]$ that is $1$ on $K$ and $0$ outside $U$.

Then $\chi_K \le f$ and so $\mu(K) \le \int_X fd\mu$ and the other inequality also seems doable. Check it out. Maybe a $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ was needed..

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95385/discussion-on-answer-by-henno-brandsma-how-to-prove-muk-le-int-limits-xfd-m).